# How to use HttpClientHandler with HttpClientFactory in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, .net-core-2.1, httpclientfactory

I want to use the `HttpClientFactory` that is available in .NET Core 2.1 but I also want to use the `HttpClientHandler` to utilize the `AutomaticDecompression` property when creating `HttpClients`.

I am struggling because the `.AddHttpMessageHandler<>` takes a `DelegatingHandler` not a `HttpClientHandler`.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually I'm not using automatic decompression but the way to achieve this is to properly register http client

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyCustomHttpClient>()
   .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder((c) =>
     new HttpClientHandler()
     {
        AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip
     }
   )
   .AddHttpMessageHandler((s) => s.GetService<MyCustomDelegatingHandler>())
```

Comment: Did not work for me . Had to use 
    .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(builder =>
                    {
                        builder.PrimaryHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
                        {
                            UseDefaultCredentials = true
                        };
                        builder.Build();
                    })

Comment: More properly use ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler() method

Comment: The first call to `ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder` in your solution does absolutely nothing, that method takes an `Action<T>` and you're just returning a value which is immediately discarded: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configurehttpmessagehandlerbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0

Answer (score 37):

More properly to define primary `HttpMessageHandler` via `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler()` method of `HttpClientBuilder`. See example below to configure typed client how.

```
services.AddHttpClient<TypedClient>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient((sp, httpClient) =>
    {
        var options = sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SomeOptions>>().Value;
        httpClient.BaseAddress = options.Url;
        httpClient.Timeout = options.RequestTimeout;
    })
    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(x => new HttpClientHandler() 
    {
        AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp => sp.GetService<SomeCustomHandler>().CreateAuthHandler())
    .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PollyPolicyName.HttpRetry)
    .AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(PollyPolicyName.HttpCircuitBreaker);
```

Also you can define error handling policy via usage of special builders methods of Polly library. In this example policy should be predefined and stored into policy registry service.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddPollyPolicies(
    this IServiceCollection services, 
    Action<PollyPoliciesOptions> setupAction = null)
{
    var policyOptions = new PollyPoliciesOptions();
    setupAction?.Invoke(policyOptions);

    var policyRegistry = services.AddPolicyRegistry();

    policyRegistry.Add(
        PollyPolicyName.HttpRetry,
        HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                policyOptions.HttpRetry.Count,
                retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(policyOptions.HttpRetry.BackoffPower, retryAttempt))));

    policyRegistry.Add(
        PollyPolicyName.HttpCircuitBreaker,
        HttpPolicyExtensions
            .HandleTransientHttpError()
            .CircuitBreakerAsync(
                handledEventsAllowedBeforeBreaking: policyOptions.HttpCircuitBreaker.ExceptionsAllowedBeforeBreaking,
                    durationOfBreak: policyOptions.HttpCircuitBreaker.DurationOfBreak));

    return services;
}
```