# How to use WinHttpHandler with IHttpClientFactory in core2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to use the new `IHttpClientFactory` with an ASP.net Core 2.1 WEB API application.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other services configuration
    services.AddHttpClient();
}
```

In my `ConfigureServices` method, I don't see a way to add the `IHttpClientFactory`and configure it to use `WinHttpHandler`.

The `AddHttpClient` methods that return a `IHttpClientBuilder` gives you access to methods that configure the `HttpMessageHandler` but those have to be derived from `DelegatingHandler` but `WinHttpHandler` does not derive from `DelegatingHandler`.

See no way to tell `HttpClient` to use `WinHttpHandler` when being constructed.

Comment: Check this similar question asked recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747749/how-to-use-httpclienthandler-with-httpclientfactory-in-net-core The suggested answer has promise based on what I have read in the source code for the builder.

Comment: Not what I needed but close, see my answer below.

Comment: Well I figured it would lead you in the right direction. Glad you figured it out. Happy coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

Thanks to tip given by @Nkosi in the comments!

I solved this by using a named `HttpClient` when registering the `HttpClient` service and then configuring the message handler to use `WinHttpHandler` as the PrimaryHandler

```
services.AddHttpClient<HttpClient>("WinHttp")
        .ConfigureHttpMessageHandlerBuilder(c =>
        {
            c.PrimaryHandler = new WinHttpHandler() { WindowsProxyUsePolicy = WindowsProxyUsePolicy.UseWinInetProxy };
        });
```

Then when using the `IHttpClientFactory`, specify the name you gave when registering it.

```
var httpClient = this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient("WinHttp");
```

Your `HttpClient` will now use `WinHttpHandler`!

**NOTE**
To use WinHttpHandler you must add nuget package [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/)